# Disabling a plugin loading when launching Vim from `git commit`

Tags: vimrc, neovim, plugin-nerdtree

Is there a way to disable a plugin only on occasions where Vim was launched from another program?

I have set Vim (Neovim, more specifically) to be the default `core.editor` of my git configuration and let's say I have these plugins in my `.vimrc` loading through vim-plug:

```
" Plugins to load with Vim
call plug#begin('~/.vim/plugged')

    Plug 'preservim/nerdtree' | Plug 'Xuyuanp/nerdtree-git-plugin'
    Plug 'itchyny/lightline.vim'
    Plug 'ryanoasis/vim-devicons'

call plug#end()

" Some variables and vimscripts directly related to a plugin
let NERDTreeShowHidden = 1

autocmd VimEnter * NERDTree | wincmd p
autocmd BufWinEnter * if getcmdwintype() == '' | silent NERDTreeMirror | endif
```

In this case, I just want to have a clean buffer ready for me to insert the commit message, so is it possible to make Vim ignore some of these plugins when commiting?

---

#### In other words:

- Is Vim capable of understanding that it was launched through `git commit` (or merely `git`)?
- Should it be capable, how must I change my `.vimrc` (either on the example above where the plugins are called or somewhere else in the file) in order to disable plugins I don't need?

  - In this case, anything related to NERDTree is irrelevant when commiting, so `nerdtree`, `nerdtree-git-plugin` and `vim-devicons` should be disabled while `lightline.vim` will keep getting loaded;
- In case I manage to disable plugins under these circumstances, should I be aware of any further changes in variables and scripts that call upon these disabled plugins (such as the ones shown above)?

Comment: Would it be acceptable if NERDTree loaded but didn't start? That would make the problem slightly easier.

Comment: @Heptite, sure, no problem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

git sets a number of environmental variables when invoked, if they're not already set in the environment. I would just test for one of those and conditionally run the NERDTree commands accordingly.

```
if !exists('$GIT_EXEC_PATH')
    autocmd VimEnter * NERDTree | wincmd p
    autocmd BufWinEnter * if getcmdwintype() == '' | silent NERDTreeMirror | endif
endif
```

Comment: Vim also sets the `gitcommit` filetype, so you can also use `if filetype != 'gitcommit' [..] endif`.

Comment: @MartinTournoij nit `&filetype`, and there's also `argv()` and `v:argv` for testing the arguments.